# Dynamic Object Translator

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom, dynamic, typecast

I am trying to create an object translator which will be used to translate my wrapper class object into an other object.

My class structure is as following

```
public class wrapperMaster
{

public class  Request 
          {
        public String ipAddress;
        public String productCode;
        public Person person;
    }

public class Person {
        public String title;
        public String firstName;
        public String middleName;
        public String lastName;

    }

}
```

Now the other class is like this.

```
public class myClass
{

   public class kv
   {
     string key;
     string value;
   }

   public class tKit
   {
      List<kv> mykvpairs;
   }
}
```

Now all the data for the fields in wrapper is in List

I want to dynamically achieve this with something like

```
public void objectTranslate(Object obj , myClass.tKit tKitObj)
{
    /*
    Obj is basically any dynamic object in this case I passed the request object from wrapper
    now fields ipAddress and productcode were easy, 
    got object type
    new instance
    converted to json
    perform string functions on json
    converted back and got an object

    but for person I am stuck so need help
   is there anyway we can know the full name of the dynamic class
  like it comes in stack trace that would help me in constructing this translator
   */
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a `Map<String, String>`? For the classes you mentioned, you can just use `JSON.serialize(obj Map<String, String>.class)`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson : this is toolkit is part of architecture I cannot change that.

Comment: @AdrianLarson the problem is not the values. I want to know the name of the super class of the wrapper so I can create and instance object of it and fill values from  key value pair.
Like for the class masterwrapper.person. When I get the type it gives me person not the super class reference.